# What is the android equivalent to the table view on an iPhone?

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me what is the equivalent component in android like table view on an iPhone?

How do I implement the table view component like on an iPhone in android?

Give an example.

Comment: Don't try to find the equivalent view as the iphone. Just implement what you want the best way you can

Comment: [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use table layout

The TableLayout groups views into rows and columns. You use the  element to designate a row in the table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#000044">
<TableRow>
  <TextView id="@+id/textName" android:text="Name:" android:textColor="#ffffff" />
  <EditText id="@+id/editName"  android:width="240px" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
  <TextView id="@+id/textPasswd" android:text="Password:" android:textColor="#ffffff" />
  <EditText id="@+id/editPasswd" android:password="true" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
  <Button id="@+id/buttonSignIn" android:text="Sign In" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Refer below links for further information

http://androiddevel.blogspot.com/2007/12/tablelayout-example.html

http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts

Answer (score 1):

TableView in iPhone is equivalent ListView in Android, but its UI is different.

I see in GitHub there is a uitableview library for Android: https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/android-uitableview

I believe that's what you're looking for.